# Event Store - Filter out any deleted streams from projections

Tags: c#, event-sourcing, eventsource, eventstoredb

I have deleted some streams but I'm still getting those streams when my projection starts.

Is there a way to filter out any deleted streams from projections?

I know that the streams have been deleted because a `StreamDeletedException` exception is being raised when I use code like this:

```
var events = _eventStoreConnection.ReadStreamAsync(
                    Direction.Forwards,
                    e.Event.EventStreamId,
                    StreamPosition.Start);
  await foreach (var @event in events)
  {
  }
```

Comment: So, you have a projection, which gives you an event and you try to read from the original event stream, then you get this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs a lot more context than what you provided.

A bit of clarification. Projections don't store streams. Projections don't store events either. Projections are computation that happens to emit events to stream(s).

It seems you are relying on `$streams` or something similar that **linked** events from streams you deleted. The distinction is important because what is stored in streams like `$streams` are actually links that point to events belonging to different streams. As such, when streams got deleted, the links that point to their events are not deleted.

In the case of `$streams`, what is stored is links to each stream first event. Links are events with a payload following this pattern `{version_number}@{stream_name}` and with the `$>` event type.

In EventStoreDB you can't delete events as you would delete a row in an SQL database, but you can delete streams (which you can see as tables if it helps)

Comment: There's quite a lot of confusion around the word "projection", and we keep discussing it internally. What Yo describes by the word "projection" is internal JS-based server-side code snippets, which receive events from certain streams and produce events to other streams, or, indeed, links. What people usually mean by "projections" is client-side code, which produce read models in some external storage. That's why we keep discussing if we should rename "projections" in ESDB to "transformations".

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you receive events from deleted streams in your subscription is because, as Yo wrote, events aren't *deleted* as such when you delete a stream.

If you subscribe to a regular stream, or a projection stream (like category), you should *not* get events from deleted streams. When subscribing to streams, which contain links, like category streams, you need to set `resolveLinkTos` to `true`.

If you, however, subscribe to `$all`, you *will* get events from deleted streams, if you start from the beginning. It's because when reading from `$all` we read directly from the event log, where events are still present. The issue is known, and we plan to solve it, but for now it's how it is. It's not causing a lot of issues because subscriptions to `$all` usually run in real-time mode and deletions aren't relevant in this case. However, when reading from the start, you indeed hit this issue.

When you run scavenging, events for deleted streams, truncated streams, also events that expired according to stream TTL and max count, will be deleted. There's an issue there too since EventStoreDB is unable to scavenge the currently active (last) chunk. It's because events are being written to this chunk, so it cannot be closed and recreated (that's how scavenging works).

The scavenging issue occurs when you have small volumes (dev, testing) and the active chunk remains the only chunk, so it never gets scavenged.

Comment: so how should we recognize and ignore deleted events in the subscriptions???
seems there is no solution in the java client

Comment: also i ran a scavenge from UI and it didn't wipe any deleted event

Comment: The reason is mentioned in the last sentence of my answer.